# How to stop fin "file pointer" from resetting back to beginning of file c++?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to read from a file of numbers to create a matrix (dimensions are specified by user). The problem is whenever I try to make a second matrix from the file, the file pointer resets and ends up shooting back the same matrix both times. I have fin passed by reference in my function because our professor said it would fix this but it hasn't stopped the pointer from resetting.

Here's my functions:

```
// creates a matrix from a file
vector<int> filefill(ifstream &fin, string file, int rowsize, int columnsize) {
    fin.open(file.c_str());
    vector<int> matrix;
    int number;

    int i=0;
        while((fin >> number) && i < rowsize*columnsize) {
            matrix.push_back(number);
            i++;
        }

    fin.close();
    return matrix;
}

// writes a matrix onto a file
void fileout(string file, vector<int> matrix) {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(file.c_str());
    for(int i=0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
        fout << matrix[i] << endl;
    fout.close();
}
```

And here's them in the main:

```
vector<int> matrixA;
vector<int> matrixB;

cout << "Would you like to fill the matrices from a file?(Y/N) ";
string answer;
cin >> answer;

if (answer == "Y" || answer == "y") {
    cout << "Please enter file name: ";
    string file;
    cin >> file;
    ifstream fin;

    matrixA = filefill(fin, file, Arow, Bcolumn);
    matrixB = filefill(fin, file, Arow, Bcolumn);
    vector<int>matrixC= addmat(matrixA, matrixB);

    cout << endl << "Type in (1) to output to file OR" << endl << "Type in (2) to output to console: ";
    string output;
    cin >> output;

    if(output == "1") {
        cout << "Enter the file name you wish to output to: ";
        string filo;
        cin >> filo;
        fileout(filo,matrixA);
        fileout(filo,matrixB);
        fileout(filo,matrixC);
    }
```

Comment: Don't open and close the file for each matrix?

Comment: Open the file  before `matrixA = ...` and close it after `matrixB = ...`

Answer (score 1):

`filefill()` opens the file each time [`fin.open(file.c_str());`].

Open the file once before calling `filefill()` and pass it in (and remove the open from inside `filefill()`. Your code already passes `fin`, so it's half way there!

edit: As JonnyHenly correctly points out - don't forget to move the `fin.close()` from `filefill()` when you move the `fin.open()`

Comment: maybe add that you should move the close from inside `filefill()` as well : )